# How to specify unprotected subdirectories in owasp.properties file?

Tags: security, csrf, owasp

I am using owasp csrfguard-3.0.0 for CSRF. I was able to specify unprotect js files from my Javascript folder using org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.JavaScript=javascript/*.js but I have other directories inside that folder as well how can I unprotect them.
e.g x/y/z is my folder structure how can I use org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected to unprotect all the files from each directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by setting unprotected using *.css/*.js so that all the files of specified type will be ignored. That also helps even though those files are from different folders.